# Make sure query is executed or not with Anorm

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, anorm

update query is returning `1` but the insert query is returning `None`.

```scala
def que3(params) {
 DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    val i=SQL("UPDATE QUERY").executeUpdate
    val j=SQL("INSERT QUERY").executeInsert
    val k=SQL("INSERT QUERY").executeInsert
    println(i)//1
    println(j)//None
    println(k)//None
 }
}
```

I want to make sure that those query is do their job or not ? how could I get this.

Or should I go for three method with try catch block?

*I am using scala 2.10 with play framework 2.2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `executeUpdate` as `executeInsert` is the same thing but returns generated id's (auto inc fields etc) if you need them. It's using the same JDBC call for both of them.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/863a9bdf78c25e9161043f3c6f8567b9e12fb3bb/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/Anorm.scala#L375

Comment: is there any way to get numbers of effected rows?

Comment: Calling executeUpdate will return the number of rows for insert statements just like it does for update statements.